# Get status of ESC/POS printer connected throughout USB in linux with Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, io, usb, escpos

I have a tg 2460 CUSTOM ticket printer that has ESC/POS emulation, USB connected in debian linux.
I'm trying to get the status of the printer in my qt c++ program with the command but with no response.

I use QFile class to deal with it, opening the device directly eg dev/usblp0 seems to bring no results so i open the mounted device eg dev/usb/lp0 and i am able to control the printer OK, but when i write the "\x10\x04\x01" command (transmission of status in real time) or any other command that implies a response i cannot get data back, using read() or readAll() hangs forever blocking the process, so how can i receive data? forgive me if i'm missing something basic

Comment: On which operating system? I guess some Linux, but you need to add the `linux` tag. Also, show some [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [QSocketNotifier](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsocketnotifier.html), assuming you are on Linux.

On Linux, `QSocketNotifier` works with any [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)-able [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) (so it is somehow incorrectly named, since you can use it on non-socket file descriptors).

<sup>(On Windows, things are incompatibly different)</sup>

BTW, you might want to use [CUPS](https://www.cups.org/) on your POS system. You could then run some `lp` (or `lpr`) command to print things (thru some [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)), perhaps thru [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html). And you'll use HTTP technology -client side- (so [Qt Network](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-index.html)) to query CUPS.

Read also about [Qt Print Support](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtprintsupport-index.html).

Consider also debugging not only [with `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) but also with [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html).

Comment: I hooked up an instance of QSocketNotifier but on /dev/usb/lp0 never got an event and on /dev/usblp0 events are fired within very short time (like polling) even if there is no data, so no solution for now but I'll look further into your links, thanks